# How can I set cursor position with OpenTK?

Tags: c#, .net, opentk

I am working on an FPS Camera with the latest version of OpenTK (2.0.0.0) and I want to use mouse delta movement to control the pitch/yaw of the camera. For that I need to reposition the cursor to the center of the window but I cannot find a way to set the cursor position. I looked under `GameWindow.Mouse` and `GameWindow.Cursor` and I only found a way to get the cursor position, not set it.

How do I set the cursor position ?

Comment: `GameWindow.Cursor` has `GetState()` and `GetCursorState()` which both return a `OpenTK.Input.MouseState`. Unfortunately, all of the properties, like `MouseState.X` and `MouseState.Y` only have public getters. There are no other methods provided to set the cursor position.

`GameWindow.Cursor` also only has public `X` and `Y` getters. I thought of setting the `Cursor.State` to a new `MouseState` but I can also get the `MouseState`...

Comment: I think I am gonna fork the develop branch and just add the setters myself, hoping it wont break anything/will work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the mouse position by using OpenTK.Input.Mouse:

```
OpenTK.Input.Mouse.SetPosition(x, y);
```